# HTTP 404 errors on trivial Flask-Restless app

Tags: flask, flask-restless

I've installed [Flask-Restless](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and am trying to run the [quickstart app](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html). All requests return a 404 error (both in the python logs and in the curl response). My whole setup is:

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install flask-restless
$ pip install flask-sqlalchemy # it doesn't appear to do this automatically
... Copy code from quickstart to "run.py" ...
$ python ./run.py

(another window)
$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

The console output from run.py is:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2013 17:08:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The `test.db` does get created, and using the debugger I can see that `app.run()` does execute.

Interestingly, I get exactly the same behavior with [Eve](http://python-eve.org/). I am able to run simple Flask apps, however.

In case it matters, this is OS X 10.8 and Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Flask-Restless [documentation](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basicusage.html)...

> By default, the API for Person, in the above code samples, will be
>   accessible at `http://<host>:<port>/api/person`, where the person part
>   of the URL is the value of `Person.__tablename__`:

My guess is that by default, these frameworks do not set up an endpoint on the path `/`. They only have endpoints defined for paths related to actual objects in your API. Try the following...

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/person
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/person
```

These URLs might actually hit your endpoints that you're defining.

Comment: Specifically it turns out to be `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/person` (which is a little surprising; I didn't realize it would lowercase it). I had assumed that the root would give some kind of Django-style "here's the API." Thanks; this was a real help. The problem continues with Eve, but that means it's a problem with Eve, not my general setup.

Comment: As I study the docs, the lowercasing comes from Flask-SQLAlchemy, which changes `CamelCase` to `camel_case`.

Comment: **[Slight Unrelated] Beware of url_prefix and __tablename__**

I spent three hours trying to figure out that. If you have a **model Person**

For eg: 
```person_blueprint = manager.create_api_blueprint(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'], url_prefix="/api")
```

You url should look like
```http://localhost:5000/api/person```


In my case, I created a blueprint this way
```person_blueprint = manager.create_api_blueprint(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'], url_prefix="/person")
```

wrong url_prefix caused a lot of 404 pain to me.